# How to handle every exception in spring boot (not rest stuff)

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I have created a spring boot application that is doing a certain job after start and returning 0 if finished:

```
@EventListener
public void onStart(ContextStartedEvent start){
    log.info("Application started.");

    doTheJob();
    log.info("Import finished.");
    applicationContext = start.getApplicationContext();
    SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 0);
}
```

This is working fine. But in case of exception the application is of course not stopping.
How to fetch every exception and return another code?

I tried just to annotate another method:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)
public void handleAll(){
    SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> -1);
}
```

But this is not called upon exception. How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Move the same method into a separate class with annotation @RestControllerAdvice and make sure that it's available for spring context

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExHandler{

@ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)
public void handleAll(){
SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> -1);
}}
```

Comment: i guess you mean "@ControllerAdvice" didn't know that this is always working (not only for "controllers" :-))

Comment: agreed!! `@RestController`advice is just a simpler way of saying `@ControllerAdvice + @ResponseBody`. Either works in this case. But `ControllerAdvice` would be more suitable as he is not trying to return anything @dermoritz.

Comment: this is not working - i tried with throwable and throwed an illegalargumentexception but my method is not called

Comment: Is the bean available witin the scope of the main application?

Comment: yes is same package, the @EventListener method is called and all beans are injected fine